# has_many, through - undefined method `relation_delegate_class'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Users class, and a UserGroup class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users_groups, through: :group_memberships

  ...

class UsersGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
```

... and a GroupMembership class to join them -

```
class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :users_groups, dependent: :destroy
```

My migrations look like this -

```
class CreateUsersGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users_groups do |t|
     t.string :title
     t.string :status
     t.string :about

     t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateGroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :group_memberships do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, index: true
      t.integer :users_group_id, index: true
      t.boolean :owner
    end
  end
end
```

So `user.group_memberships` is perfectly happy, but `user.users_groups` returns an error -

```
undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Users:Module
```

Similarly, `users_group.group_memberships` is fine, but `users_group.users` returns *exactly the same error* -

```
undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Users:Module
```

... on the users module. I've stared at this for a couple of hours, but I'm sure it's simple syntax somewhere. What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using belongs_to I believe you need to use a singular format:
So not `belongs_to :users` but `belongs_to :user`

```
class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :writers_group, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: @RADan Sometimes we just need an extra pair of eyes

Answer (score -1):

I believe that since you are using 'through' you will have to use:

`user.group_memberships.users_groups`

This is because users does not have users_groups or vice versa.

Instead you access the users_groups through group_memberships.

Comment: This is wrong as that is the whole reason `has_many through` exists.